# C# and WCF Reference issue

Tags: c#, wcf

Got all mixed up and I'm sure it's a silly one.
Solution:

Project 1. **Compania.**
Linea.cs: Just the **Linea** class with different constructors and that's it for now.

Project 2. **Bandeja.**
Class.cs: Here I wrote all the methods I'll be needing when working with **Linea**. (getLinea() is the one I'll be showing you in the example below)

Project 3. **WCFWebService.**
A WCF service calling the C# methods.

References.

from Bandeja to Compania.

from WCFWebService to Compania.

from WCFWebService to Bandeja.

The only one error I get while building comes from the service.

**Service Class**

```
namespace WCFWebService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class WSBandeja : IWSBandeja
    {
        public Compania.Linea getLinea()
        {
            Compania.Linea linea = new Compania.Linea();
            return linea.

        }

    }
}
```

When I enter return.linea. I can't find the method getLinea() contained in class.cs inside Project Bandeja, just the parameters.

Any suggestion is most welcome since I'm new to C# and WebServices.
Thanks.

**EDIT.
Compania Project - Linea.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Compania
{
    public class Linea
    {
        public string ani { get; set; }
        public int teleprom { get; set; }
        public string actividad { get; set; }
        public DateTime fechaIngreso { get; set; }
        public string reclamo { get; set; }
        public string producto { get; set; }
        public string observacion { get; set; }
        public int tipoActividad { get; set; }
        public string tipoAveria { get; set; }
        public int reiteros { get; set; }
        public int call { get; set; }
        public bool trabajado { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Bandeja Project - Class.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;

namespace Bandeja
{
    public class Bandeja
    {
        public static string getNewConnection()
        {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BO"].ConnectionString;
        }

        public Compania.Linea getLinea()
        {
            var cLinea = new Compania.Linea();
            string connectionString = getNewConnection();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            using(conn)
            { 
                string variable = "GESTIONAR MANUALMENTE";
                var command = new SqlCommand("Bandeja_test");
                command.Connection = conn; 
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@linea", variable));
                conn.Open();
                SqlDataReader newReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (newReader.Read())
                {
                    cLinea = new Compania.Linea();
                    cLinea.ani = newReader["Línea"].ToString();
                    cLinea.fechaIngreso = Convert.ToDateTime(newReader["Fecha Ingreso"]);
                    cLinea.producto = newReader["Producto"].ToString();
                    cLinea.observacion = newReader["Observación"].ToString();
                }
            }

            return cLinea;
        }

    }

}
```

**The Web Service Interface.**

```
namespace WCFWebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IWSBandeja
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Compania.Linea getLinea();

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the relation between classes Linea and Bandeja (or whatever) and how is the Linea class used in project Bandeja?

Comment: In project bandeja, class.cs I have methods, one of them is getLinea. In there I create a new Linea object and connect to a SQL db to get data, then I return the object. So the methods work with Linea objects

Comment: Can you please post the classes also?

Comment: The names are somewhat confusing. 'WSBandeja' seems like a service implementation since it seems to be implementing the interface 'IWSBandeja'. So why is it marked with a 'DataContract' attribute? That would make it a data-container and the methods will not be visible over a WCF proxy. Not exactly sure if that's what you are trying to do. Hope this helps.

Comment: WSBandeja stands for WebServiceBandeja. Bandeja is the name of the primary project. So, the intention this web service is for 'XMLing' the data coming back from these C#. In The WCF WS I have the interface which has no errors, and the service class itself. That's the [DataContract] code that you see, and I think the DataContract and the skeleton of the code is fine, but somehow I can't invoke the method contained in Bandeja -> class.cs

Comment: Does the error occur in your first code snippet?

Comment: Yes, in the Service class of the WCF Project. It is incomplete (what I've posted) because after the return.linea.(here the intelligence should give me the methods) I get nothing but parameters of the Linea class and GetHash, GetType, Equals, etc.

Comment: @DanielSh. think by "parameters" you mean "properties".  Either way, how is it that you expect to be able to call methods defined in Bandeja from an instantiation of Linea?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Jeff Yes, properties, sorry my bad. And I agree with you, but what can I do to call the method in Bandeja from Linea? I cant reference Linea to Bandeja because it throws an error of circular dependency. I'm missing something since I'm new to OO

Comment: @DanielSh. To call methods defined in Bandeja you have to instantiate Bandeja.  var bandeja = new Bandeja();  Then you can use the dot operator on bandeha to call whatever methods are defined.  In the code you posted you are instantiating Linea, which will only provide access to methods and properties in Linea.

Comment: In fact, it appears @channs has posted the answer below:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are instantiating the wrong class. Try this.

```
[DataContract]
    public class WSBandeja : IWSBandeja
    {
        public Compania.Linea getLinea()
        {
            Bandeja.Bandeja bandeja = new Bandeja.Bandeja();
            return bandeja.getLinea();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If i do: "return bandeja.bandeja." I get Equals, ReferenceEquals and getNewConnection. getNewConnection is a method written by me, but I can't see getLinea() which is the one I want.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[ServiceContract]
    public class WSBandeja : IWSBandeja
    {
        [OperationContract]
        public Compania.Linea getLinea()
        {
            Compania.Linea linea = new Compania.Linea();
            return linea.
        }
    }
```

And then define a [DataContract] for the complex type

```
namespace Compania
{
[DataContract]
public class Linea
{

    [DataMember]
    //whatever properties you have
}
```

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx) for more info on DataContracts and complex types

Comment: My original idea was to not add DataMembers in the Service class since I want to use what I've been doing in the other project classes. I'd like the WCF to use Linea objects contained in Linea class, and call the methods in Bandeja.